# Powershell read and write file (Get-Content, Set-Content): How to use?

Tags: powershell

When I read a file into a variable

```
$file = Get-Content myfile.utf8
```

and then write this same content into a new file

```
Set-Content -Encoding utf8 mynewfile.txt $file
```

Powershell automatically adds a return and linefeed to the end of the file.

How can I get the content of a file and write it back without Powershell adding anything?

Comment: It also adds a byte order mark (EFBBBF).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround from this [site](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/524739/need-nonewline-parameter-on-out-file-add-content-and-set-content).

Use

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($path, $text)
```

Comment: For me that doesn't write anything to anything.